# Why is my wireless network no longer listed in NetworkManager

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I have a problem where I'm getting disconnected from my wireless network. If I look in the list of NetworkManger it is no longer there, but if I run `iwlist wlan0 scan` it is found.

```
$ iwlist wlan0 scan | grep UPC241546362
                ESSID:"UPC241546362"

$ nm-tool | grep UPC241546362
$
```

Note that `nm-tool` is showing a number of other wireless networks.

When I disable then enable wireless networking through NM in the icon-tray, the network is found again and the connection is reestablished.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Someone might be able to answer if you update and include this information in your question: `sudo lshw -C network` and `lsmod | grep ath` and `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` and `sudo dmidecode | less | grep 'Product\|Vendor\|Version'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arnold,

There are 2 files that may benefit you to become familiar with:

```
/etc/interfaces
/etc/NetworkManager.conf
```

I mention these because I have resolved a networking issue by using the "turn if off and on again" method with them.  You could modify your `/etc/NetworkManager.conf` file to read `managed=false`, save, and back to `managed=true`.  Here's what mine looks like:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

You could modify the file using the command: `gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

The more-likely answer to your question may be found in the Official Documentation here: [Why does my wireless network keep disconnecting?](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-disconnecting.html)

The [troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html) can be very helpful, which starts by clicking Next in the top-right corner of the page.